# SQL querying for set of distinctive values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a DB table with columns ID, time, and text.  ID is non-unique.  I'm trying to construct a query that says "For each distinct IDs, give me the row whose time is the greatest value before T".  The second part is easy enough with a ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE time < T, but I don't know how to ensure I get coverage of all the IDs.

As an example:

```
ID,time,text
1,10,"hello"
1,20,"world"
2,10,"foo"
3,10,"bar"
4,50,"blah"
```

If I searched with time 25, I'd want:

```
1,20,"world"
2,10,"foo"
3,10,"bar"
```

I could do this is multiple queries by searching for DISTINCT IDs and then doing a search for each, but I was hoping there was a more efficient compound query form.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.time, t.text
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(time) AS MaxTime
                        FROM YourTable
                        WHERE time < T
                        GROUP BY ID) q
            ON t.ID = q.ID
                AND t.time = q.MaxTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query:

```
select t1.id, t1.time, t1.test
from yourtable t1
inner join 
(
    select id, max(time) MaxTime
    from yourtable
    where time < T
    group by id
) t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.time = t2.time
```